# System boot order not found. Initializing defaults

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot, boot-order

I've installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** with a USB stick. Earlier I booted the USB stick in GPT partition scheme, and in my bios, boot option is set to UEFI without CSM. My installation was successful. Then comes the issue.
It keeps saying **System boot order not found. Initializing defaults** on the Startup.
My machine is **HP ProBook 450 G2**

Ultimately the OS appears to be working but with the message showing at the beginning every time I run it.

What I tried to fix this?

#1. I tried choosing between **Secure Boot** on/off; but no luck!

#2. Then I found something like this in an Ubuntu forum:
Go to terminal:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /boot/efi/EFI
# mv BOOT BOOT_back
# cp -R ubuntu BOOT
# cd BOOT
# mv shimx64.efi bootx64.efi
```

After doing this it seemed to be working, Alas! only for the first time. Later it started shooting the same message every time I run it.

I'm still a pretty novice in Ubuntu. There must be any solution to this, Can somebody tell me what that is? Thanks.

Comment: Is the drive containing the ESP (EFI partition) the first in order?

Comment: Yes, while installing the OS I placed EFI partition in the first position. @ChanganAuto

Comment: No, you couldn't have done that while installing :) I asked whether the *drive* that contains the EFI partition is correctly set as the first in UEFI's boot order.

Comment: It was Efi system partition that I had placed in the first position. But If I'm not mistaken are you talking about something in Bios that says Boot order? If that so, NO! EFI partition is not set in the first place. @ChanganAuto

Comment: In my UEFI Boot order contains the following: 
PCIe/M.2 SSD Hard Drive,
OS Boot Manager,
USB Hard Drive,
Notebook Ethernet IPV4,
Notebook Ethernet IPV6,
Optical Disk Drive,
SD card,
Generic USB Device, 
Customized Boot

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I'm still not being completely understood. But moving on, I think that in your case you should have OS Boot Manager first. Try that and report back.

Comment: You need to understand UEFI which is what you have, not BIOS (UEFI replaced BIOS since around 2009-2012). You need to understand that it boots quite differently, has different requirements for a certain proprietary OS and it's no longer a matter of "booting drives" like it was with BIOS. UEFI boots from efi files in the EFI partition. Some UEFIs have a separated setting for the drives boot order - **where the drive containing EFI should be first - and another for selecting different OSes or other boot entries **that are read fom the EFI partition**. (...)

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with your own firmware and its settings, it varies a lot. By now you should understand why my initial suspicion regarding your error has to do with the possibility that you have the correct bootloaders entries - it wouldn't boot at all otherwise - but also **that the drive where the EFI is may not be the first in the aforementioned setting**, thus resulting in the error at first attempt. It has *nothing* to do where the system partition is, it can be a different physical drive, doesn't matter. What matters in UEFI mode is always the EFI partition,nothing else.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto , I tried shifting the OS Boot Manager at the top, But still same error. Does it have anything to do with /boot/efi/EFI directory?